# Tooltip v1.3 with nested elements

Tags: jquery, plugins, nested, tooltip

I have a problem with tooltips for nested divs, using the 1.3 version of the [jquery tooltip plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/).

There are two divs:

```
<div class="div1" title="title1">
    <p>some text</p>
    <div class="div2" title="title2">
        some content
    </div>
</div>
```

this works fine:

```
$('.div1').tooltip();
```

now, when I set the tooltip for the nested div:

```
$('.div2').tooltip();
```

It doesn't work. The tooltip for `.div1` is displayed all the time, doesn't matter if mouse is over `.div1` or `.div2`

Where is the problem?

Comment: Try reading this - http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Comment: " Event bubbling in Javascript " - google search